# how to check number of args

Tags: javascript, if-statement, discord, discord.js

I want my code to check that the person is inputting 2 or more arguments. I tried using if statements. I'm not sure if that's what I should use or should I try a function statement? My current code is:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    description: "report a naughty person",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){ 
    const reason = args.splice(1)

if (arguments.length >= 2){ 

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#1ed700')
        .setTitle('Report \n')
        .setDescription(`Person who reported ${message.author} \n`
        + `Channel reported in: ${message.channel}\n`
        + `Person reported: ${args[0]} \n` //The second argument
        + `Reason reported: ${reason.join(' ')}`) // The third argument
         

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    message.channel.send(`<@&${process.env.DUMMY_ROLE}>`)
    
    }else if (arguments.length < 2) {
        message.channel.send('Command is not written properly')

}}};
```

Currently, the if statements aren't really doing anything to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using `arguments.length` when it seems to be`args.length` instead.

I say this, because you are using`args` as part of your variables above in your code, but checking`arguments` instead; if not declared, will always be undefined.

Also, I would remove the `else if` statement and use `else` only

Comment: So after doing that it only does the second one and says "Code is not written properly" I'm not sure if its an issue with the way the >= statement or if the if statement is written wrong.

Comment: can you print your `args` variable and your `arguments` variable I the console and update your question with them?

Comment: so it says the length is 1 either way. The issue is if i do a mention its also equal to 1. I want it to check if it has both the mention and the reason.

Comment: It's impossible to know, unless you slow us the console for each and we can see what properties each object has. Do not print the length, but the object in the console

Comment: sorry but um how would i check the properties?

Comment: By using: `Console.log(args)`

Answer (score 1):

Change all your `arguments` to `args`. Because `arguments` is